# Construção CASE Firebird

Tags: firebird, firebird-2.5

Preciso Construir um estrutura `CASE` no **SQL Firebird** só que não está aceitando o modo que eu estou fazendo.

```
SELECT 
  CONTAS_RECEBER.ID,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.DT_VENC,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.TIPO_OPERACAO,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO,
  CASE
    WHEN CONTAS_RECEBER.TIPO_OPERACAO = 'DAV'  THEN
       (SELECT VENDEDOR.DESCRICAO FROM DAV LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR on(VENDEDOR.ID=DAV.ID_VENDEDOR) WHERE DAV.ID CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO) 

    WHEN CONTAS_RECEBER.TIPO_OPERACAO = 'NFCe' THEN
       (SELECT VENDEDOR.DESCRICAO FROM NFCE LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR on (VENDEDOR.ID = NFCE.ID_VENDEDOR) WHERE NFCE.ID CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO)

    WHEN CONTAS_RECEBER.TIPO_OPERACAO = 'NFe' THEN
       (SELECT VENDEDOR.DESCRICAO FROM NFE LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR on (VENDEDOR.ID = NFE.ID_VENDEDOR) WHERE NFE.ID CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO)
  ELSE 'VENDEDOR NÃO INFORMADO'  END AS NOME_VENDEDOR,  
  CONTAS_RECEBER.VLR_QUITACAO AS VLR_PAGO,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.VLR_CONTA
FROM
  CONTAS_RECEBER
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENTES ON (CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE = CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_CLIENTE)
```

O erro que aparece é esse:

> ```
> Invalid token.
> Dynamic SQL Error.
> SQL error code = -104.
> Token unknown - line 12, column 105.
> CONTAS_RECEBER.
> ```

tenho que buscar também o nome do vendedor que está na tabela de vendedor, e a tabela Contas a Receber faz ligação com as tabelas que contem o ID do Vendedor, essas referencias estão em `CONTAS_RECEBER.TIPO_OPERACAO`, que da o nome da tabela onde eu vou encontra o ID do Vendedor e `CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO` que é o ID identifica a venda.

Se precisar de mais informações só pedir.

Comment: Consulte o manual pois creio que este tipo de construção não é permitido no padrão SQL. De qualquer forma faltou o operando em suas cláusulas WHERE. Uma alternativa é você fazer todos os join no SELECT e utilizar os campos do resultado na expressão CASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que diz no [firebirdsql.org](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-case.html#langrefupd15-case-simple), no `CASE` só vai aceitar como resultado valores *literais* ou *variáveis*, *expressões compostas* ou *NULL literais*.

só que no seu código está faltando uma coias o Operador "***=***" na clausula **WHERE do Select dentro do case** por isso ocorre o erro. vou colocar seu código corrigido aqui.

```
SELECT 
  CONTAS_RECEBER.ID,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.DT_VENC,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.TIPO_OPERACAO,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO,
  CASE CONTAS_RECEBER.TIPO_OPERACAO
    WHEN 'DAV'  THEN (SELECT VENDEDOR.DESCRICAO FROM DAV  LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR on (VENDEDOR.ID = DAV.ID_VENDEDOR)  WHERE DAV.ID  = CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO) 
    WHEN 'NFCe' THEN (SELECT VENDEDOR.DESCRICAO FROM NFCE LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR on (VENDEDOR.ID = NFCE.ID_VENDEDOR) WHERE NFCE.ID = CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO)
    WHEN 'NFe'  THEN (SELECT VENDEDOR.DESCRICAO FROM NFE  LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR on (VENDEDOR.ID = NFE.ID_VENDEDOR)  WHERE NFE.ID  = CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_OPERACAO)
    ELSE 'SEM VENDEDOR'
  END AS NOME_VENDEDOR,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.VLR_QUITACAO AS VLR_PAGO,
  CONTAS_RECEBER.VLR_CONTA
FROM
  CONTAS_RECEBER
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENTES ON (CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE = CONTAS_RECEBER.ID_CLIENTE)
```